# Exporting MailEnable Mail Boxes to Another Mail Service

Tags: email, hosting, mailenable

I'm trying to move my hosting mailboxes to Google Workspace.
Currently I use MailEnable on my hosting.

The problem is, I could not export my mails.

I tried:

1. I could not choose and download mails for all mails. If I tried to download them one by one. There was an extra '.mai' extension file. I have a lot of mails that I can not download it one by one.
2. I could not forward all mails to another mail. I can do it one by one, but also, there are too many mails not to do it one by one.
3. We thought that we maybe use Outlook to get them. But, my hosting uses POP3 for mailing, then I could not get **sent emails**. Also I need them. But I can get incoming mails. I can not retrieve outgoing mails.
4. We want to move our mails to Google Workspace without any loss.

What is the solution?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about managing your servers should be asked on [sf]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a tiring road but
I connected mailboxes to outlook. Get them. After that I restore my mail to the new mail server.